# how to implement on android an interface to compose lucene query?

Tags: java, android, lucene, android-widget, full-text-search

I have on my server a parser and a searcher for lucene query that search on xml and i have an android application that use this service.

Until now this android application has used the searcher in a simple way. Writing something on a text widget and clicking on a button it's like search:

```
title: something
```

It's found all the files which have on title "something".

But the service permit to me to search things like:

```
mediatype:audio AND mtime:[45dayago TO now] AND metadata_count:[04 TO 99]
```

More info on lucene query are [here](https://lucene.apache.org/core/3_0_3/queryparsersyntax.html).

For user it's realy difficult know what terms are valid or how to describe advanced query but it's realy important to search on an archive. I would try to make an easy and valid lucene query to help the user to use that advanced search experience.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me, I'd start by constructing a view that has an arbitrary number of TextEdit boxes (the user can select how many, possibly via a spinner or a "add more" button). Then have a selector whether these terms are to be "ANDed" or "ORed" together.

Once you have that working, enhance each entry to be more than just a TextEdit, but to have options for entering numbers (via spinners?), ranges (via slider?) or dates/times (via a calendar picker?)?

The key here is to take an iterative approach. Implement one additional capability, and make sure it works, before moving on to the next one.

Comment: A new Activity with this new view it's realy better of what i was thinking. (To implement everything by dialog in the same view). I'm looking for a view example too. [Here](https://www.google.com/advanced_search) the google's approach, but this is for web not for phone